# MongoDB: how to count number of keys in a document?

Tags: mongodb

Lets say a document is :

```
{

a: 1,
b: 1,
c: 2,
 ....
z: 2
}
```

How can I count the number of keys in such document?

Thank you

Comment: Why is this getting a downvote? It's a fairly legitimate question. Upvoting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no built-in command for that. Fetch this document and count the keys yourself.

Comment: @daydreamer: choose another answer. A command exists for this now.

Answer (score 22):

Quite possible if using MongoDB 3.6 and newer though the aggregation framework.
Use the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator within an aggregation pipeline to convert the document to an array. The return array contains an element for each field/value pair in the original document. Each element in the return array is a document that contains two fields `k` and `v`.

The reference to root the document is made possible through the **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)** system variable which references the top-level document currently being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage.

On getting the array, you can then leverage the use of [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline step to create a field that holds the counts and the actual count is derived with the use of the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)** operator.

All this can be done in a single pipeline by nesting the expressions as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "count": {
            "$size": { 
                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    } }     
])
```

**Example Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7cd94520a31e44e0e7e282"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "b" : 1.0,
    "c" : 2.0,
    "z" : 2.0,
    "count" : 5
}
```

---

To exclude the `_id` field, you can use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "count": {
                "$size": { 
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$el.k", "_id" ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }     
])
```

or as suggested by [0zkr PM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255390/0zkr-pm) simply add a [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline step at the beginning:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "_id": 0 } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "count": {
            "$size": { 
                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    } }     
])
```

Comment: In place of `filter` just add a `$project` to the aggregate pipeline.

Answer (score 8):

In Mongo (as in most NoSQL solutions) it's usually a good idea to pre-calculate such values if you want to do queries on them later (e.g. "where the number of different keys > 12") so maybe you should consider adding a new field "keyCount" which you increment every time a new key is added.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Mongo console, you can write javascript to do that.

```
doc = db.coll.findOne({}); nKeys =0; for( k in doc){nKeys ++;} print(nKeys);
```

This will still be considered "outside the mongo" though.

Comment: You can also just do `nKeys = Object.keys(doc).length;`

Answer (score 1):

Sergio is right, you have to do it outside of mongo.

You can do something like this:

```
var count = 0;
for(k in obj) {count++;}
print(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const MongoClient = new require("mongodb").MongoClient(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }
);
(async () => {
  const connection = await MongoClient.connect();
  const dbStuff = await connection
    .db("db")
    .collection("weedmaps.com/brands")
    .find({})
    .toArray();  // <- Chuck all it into an Array
  for (let thing of dbStuff) {
    console.log(Object.keys(thing).length);
  }
  return await connection.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are work with *Documents* like the **mongoose.Document**, You can try to count all keys inside the *doc* after transform in a object, 'cause, before it, the *doc* just have commom properties:

```
Object.keys(document); // returns [ '$__', 'isNew', 'errors', '_doc', '$locals' ]
Object.keys(document).length; // returns ALWAYS 5
```

So, try cast to an object, after pass it to **Object.keys**

```
console.dir(
    Object.keys(document.toObject()) // Returns ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']
);
```

And to show the keys count

```
console.log(
    Object.keys(document.toObject().length)
); // Returns 3
```

And Be Happy!!!