# Query the map size in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose you have a map of variable size in mongodb. 
How can you get documents that have only a certain map size, for example >2?

```
{map:{k1:v1, k2:v2, k3,v3}} 
{map:{k1:v1, k2:v2}}
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a built in function that can get you the number of keys in an object.  You would have to query each document, and then calculate the number of keys yourself. Let me know if I'm reading your question correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980145/mongodb-how-to-count-number-of-keys-in-a-document

Answer (score 3):

**With MongoDB 3.6 and greater:**

Use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator in your query, this allows you to use aggregation framework operators in particular the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator that converts the map subdocument to an array of key values i.e.

```
{ map: {
    k1:v1, 
    k2:v2, 
    k3,v3
}}
```

is transformed to the array

```
{ map: [
    { k: 'k1', v: 'v1' }, 
    { k: 'k2', v: 'v2' }, 
    { k: 'k3', v: 'v3' }
]}
```

With the array you can then use $size to get the length and compare using the comparison query operator **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt)**.

An example follows which shows the complete query:

```
db.test.find({
    "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
            { "$size": { "$objectToArray": "$map" } },
            2
        ]
    }
})
```

---

For MongoDB versions which do not have support for the above operators, you'd need to pre-calculate such map size if you want to do queries on them later so consider creating a new field `"keyCount"` which holds the number of keys for the map subdocument. Consider the following demonstration:

**Populate test collection**

```
db.test.insert([    
    {   
        "_id" : 1,  
        "map" : {
            "k1" : "v1",
            "k2" : "v2",
            "k3" : "v3"
        }
    },
    {       
        "_id" : 2,
        "map" : {
            "k1" : "v1",
            "k2" : "v2"
        }
    }
 ]);
```

As with the current design, you would need a mechanism to get all count of the keys inside the map document. This is possible through **[Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce)**. The following mapreduce operation will populate a separate collection with the new field `"keyCount"` added:

```
var mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "test",
    "map" : function() {
        var obj = this;
        obj['keyCount'] = Object.keys(this.map).length;
        emit(this._id, obj); 
    },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
    "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
})
```

To get documents that have only a certain map size, for example `> 2`, run the query on the resulting collection:

```
db[mr.result].find({ "value.keyCount": { "$gt": 2 } });
```

**Map Reduce Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : "my_collection_keys",
    "timeMillis" : 7,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 2,
        "emit" : 2,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 2
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Query Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "value" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "map" : {
            "k1" : "v1",
            "k2" : "v2",
            "k3" : "v3"
        },
        "keyCount" : 3
    }
}
```