# Querying MongoDB subdocuments without respecting key order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query against a subdocument. The problem is, that MongoDB seems to respect the order of the object keys. So if I do the following query, I won't receive any results:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({docId:'tLDmtdeYuG9DiGGrL',optimizeParams:{"deviceType":"mobile","daytime":"night"}})
```

If I change the order of optimizeParams, I will get a result:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({docId:'tLDmtdeYuG9DiGGrL',optimizeParams:{"daytime":"night","deviceType":"mobile"}})
```

Now a soultion would be to use dot notation, but in this case, I will receive ALL documents which contains both keys. But I only want the documents that ONLY have both keys (no others):

```
db.getCollection('test').find({docId:'tLDmtdeYuG9DiGGrL',"optimizeParams.deviceType":"mobile","optimizeParams.daytime":"night"})
```

Is there a way how I can execute a query without respecting the key order?

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was a way to respect they key orders, I would recommend not to use it. JSON documents are meant to not respect the key orders. You should be designing your schema with this in mind.

For your particular use case, you could do this if you're using version 3.6 or higher:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "optimizeParams.daytime": "night",
        "optimizeParams.deviceType": "mobile"
    },
},{
    $addFields: {
        count: {
            $size: {
                $objectToArray: "$optimizeParams"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        count: 2
    }
}])
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696366/5800527) helped me with the above solution. Please keep indexes in mind when using it.

Although this could be done, "find documents with only these two keys" seems to be irrelevant from any application's perspective. There must be something meaningful that this situation represents. You could use another field to indicate that meaning, and use that to filter instead.