# Count number of leaf entries in MongoDB collection

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to see the number of elements I have in my MongoDB collection.

I am aware of db.collection(count), but it returns the number of documents in my collection.
I need the total number of entries within each document.

For instance:

```
   "mass":{
      "value":314.47
      },
   "meltingPoint":[
      {
         "temp":{
            "value":337.15
         }
      }
   ]
```

The output should be 2. I am not interested in the intermediate keys or values, just the terminal values with data.

Are there any solutions for this? My mind is blanking.

Comment: I found a similar entry here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980145/mongodb-how-to-count-number-of-keys-in-a-document with answers that could help you. Personnally, I'd go for the transform Document into array solution in an aggregate pipeline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: how to count number of keys in a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980145/mongodb-how-to-count-number-of-keys-in-a-document)